# pdflatex says "Non-PDF special ignored!" trying to draw \circle in picture environment

Tags: pdftex, circles, picture-mode, specials

I have several `\circle{}`'s in a picture environment that are drawn perfectly when the .tex file is run with `latex`, and the resulting .dvi is run through `dvipdf` to produce a .pdf

But running the .tex file directly with `pdflatex` produces the overall picture okay, *except* for the `\circle{}`'s which don't show up at all. Instead, at the point where they should be drawn during processing, `pdflatex` emits four **Non-PDF special ignored!** for each. Here are the first two sets of four (note that I have no idea what it all means:)...

```
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> pn 5
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> pa 0 0
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> pa 107 -142
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> fp
] [12] [13] [14
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> pn 5
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> ar 0 0 750 750 0 6.2832
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> pn 5
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> ar 0 0 625 625 0 6.2832
```

Any way I can get the circles drawn when directly running the .tex file with `pdflatex`?

E d i t
--------------
As per @SchrodingersCat request, here's a small working example (i.e., working when run with `latex` and then `dvipdf`, but not working when run with `pdflatex`)...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eepic}
\begin{document}
Hello, world.
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1.0in}
    \begin{picture}(3,2)
      \put(0,0){\framebox(3,2){ }}
      \put(1.125,1){\circle{1.5}}
      \put(1.875,1){\circle{1.25}}
    \end{picture}
  \end{center}
Goodbye, world.
\end{document}
```

Couldn't be simpler, right? But just doesn't work when directly run with `pdflatex`. And by the way, before you even ask, my `pdflatex --version` says...

```
bash-5.0$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018 on Slackware)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.35; using libpng 1.6.36
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.68.0
```

Comment: Please post a small compilable document that illustrates the issue.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Done. (P.S. you might want to maybe remove that apostrophe from your name -- the way it breaks the string in replies, ends up looking  like a pile of Schrodinger's #2 **:)**

Comment: @JohnForkosh The `eepic` package is for DVI output only. Try `pict2e` instead

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks, Phelype. Fixed it right up!!! My bad, didn't know about that. And post that as an answer if you'd like another check (though it doesn't look like you'd need any more). Thanks again. (P.S. re ocean engineering, I spent a little (very little) time aboard the Vema and Conrad at LDEO during the early 1970's (LDGO at the time), and am still a recreational sailor)

Comment: @JohnForkosh You're welcome, and no worries, no one knows every package there is (I didn't know about `eepic` ;-). As for ocean engineering, I'd say mine is more like an “office engineering” (which is much less interesting), so some on-board experience would be definitely interesting

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Get out of the office!!! You don't know what you're missing! It's a whole other wonderful world. (Well, okay, maybe I'm a little prejudiced)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: use the `pict2e` package instead of `eepic`. The latter only supports DVI output, while `pict2e` supports a range (most?) of output formats.

---

Slightly longer answer, to clarify the “note that I have no idea what it all means” :-)

TeX itself has no knowledge of colour, drawing, or external graphics inclusion. The way this features are implemented depend on the output format (PDF, DVI, PS, etc.), and they are implemented in packages using a `\special`. A `\special` allows you to write things directly to the output file without TeX's intervention. However this lack of syntax checking allows you to write possibly invalid code to the output.

The `eepic` (and its predecessor `epic`) package only support DVI output because they contain DVI `\special`s in their code, but since they were written back when there was *only* DVI output, no verification whatsoever is done to see if the package is running on a valid engine. When you run that package with pdfTeX, the engine itself complains that a invalid `\special` was used, for example `pn 5`, which changes the line width:

```
Non-PDF special ignored!
<special> pn 5
```

The relatively more recent `pict2e` package allows multiple output formats, so you can use it with either `pdflatex` or `latex` + `dvipdf`. For PDF output `pict2e` would, for example, replace the `pn` instruction above by the equivalent PDF instruction `w`.

Comment: Thanks again, and for the clarifying info. The original document was from the early 1990's (although it was 2e rather than 2.09), and when rewriting it I just imported the preamble stuff. That eepic/pict2e problem wouldn't have ever crossed my mind had you not pointed it out.

Comment: @JohnForkosh Ah, that explains it. pdfTeX dates from the end of the 1990's (I'm not sure what year), so DVI was basically the only option